# How to use event system in Cake 3.x to call the Auth->setUser?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using Cake 3.2

I have no issues using EVent system to update statistics using my own events taht are dispatched at the afterSave for Tables.

I want to do something similar where at the end of the `add` action for a controller, I want to dispatch an event, say `Controller.Accounts.afterAdd`

That event will then be caught by an AccountListener that will then attempt to call the `Auth->user($newUser)`.

I have no luck getting the AccountListener to be activated.

Please advise.

my code:

inside bootstrap.php

```
require ROOT . DS . 'config' . DS . 'events.php';
```

inside AccountListener

```
<?php
namespace App\Event;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class AccountListener implements EventListenerInterface
{

    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Controller.Accounts.afterAdd' => 'updateStats',
        ];
    }

    public function updateStats($event, $controller)
    {
        \Cake\Log\Log::write('error', 'how does this work?');
        \Cake\Log\Log::write('error', $event);
        \Cake\Log\Log::write('error', $controller);
        $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $user = $controller->Auth->user();
        $newUser = $usersTable->find()->contain(['Groups', 'Accounts'])->where(['Users.id' => $user['id']])->hydrate(false)->first();
        $controller->Auth->setUser($user);
        $controller->set('authUser', $user);
    }
}
```

inside AccountsController:

```
public function add()
{
    ...

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       ...
       $event = new Event('Controller.Accounts.afterAdd', $this, [
         'controller' => $this
       ]);
       $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
    }
```

Inside `config/events.php`

```
<?php

use App\Event\AccountListener;

use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventManager;

EventManager::instance()->on(new AccountListener());
```

Comment: I don't see you registering the listener anywhere?

Comment: added in now. missed it out the first time.

Comment: Looks good to me. So what exactly does "_no luck getting the AccountListener to be activated_" mean? That the listener is not being invoked?

Comment: It's not invoked. yes. U noticed that I have Log::write statements? they are not executed.

Comment: Well, I just gave it a try with your exact code, and it works just fine, so I guess there's something specific to your app that you'll have to debug. For starters I'd check whether your listener is actually still registered when you're dispatching the event, ie before invoking `$this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);` check `debug($this->eventManager()->listeners('Controller.Accounts.afterAdd'));`.

Comment: You mean you used my code exactly? My biggest fear was `$event = new Event('Controller.Accounts.afterAdd', $this, [
         'controller' => $this
       ]);` actually. Not sure how the parameters work exactly.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily have to pass the controller in the data in case it's already the subject, as you can retrieve that via `$event->subject()` in your listener, but that's nothing that would cause any problem in the dispatching process. And yes, I used your exact code, copied 1:1 (except for the `...` of course), and it works fine (fine as in the listener is being invoked).

Comment: Okay. I go try again. Last question, the intention of this code is such that I can update certain fields found inside the Auth->user upon certain actions being completed. Is my way following the cake way?